# Get category by url-key (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, categories

I'm trying to get exact category from all categories and list subcategories into a page.

How to get category by it's url-key, not url-key from category?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[image]
iF  url key $urlkey = 'shirt';

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addNameToResult()
                ->addUrlRewriteToResult()
               ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$urlkey )
            ->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the category model by url key using this code:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'your-url-key')
        ->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier method:

```php
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->loadByAttribute('url_key', 'buy-now');
```